# How to best forecast tax liability for the purposes of estimated tax payments?

Tags: united-states, taxes, estimated-taxes

How can you "expect" to know if you need to pay quarterly taxes? I am on a university fellowship where there is no withholding. I am married, filing jointly. To file quarterly, my understanding from a [previous question here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/157045/do-i-need-to-make-quarterly-estimated-tax-payments-for-a-post-doc-fellowship) is that I need to *expect* to owe at least $1000 for 2023. If I don't know this per se but end up owing more than that, will I still be penalized with late fees for not having filed quarterly in the first place?

And if I do file quarterly, what documentation do I need? My wife receives her W2 only once per year along with our 1099-INTs, and I receive no tax forms from my university documenting my fellowship (this seems strange, but I have checked this multiple times with them). We are both US citizens, if that matters.

Comment: You don't file a complete return, you go through the 1040-ES form to "guesstimate" how much tax you may owe, send in quarterly payments, and by April of 2024 file a complete 1040 return and either owe a bit or get some back...

Comment: Thanks, does that retroactively take into account missing the first quarterly estimate (I missed this since I didn't know this until now)? And I guess there's something similar for states? I am in Missouri if that matters.

Comment: Pay the amount with the remaining 'quarterly' payments and all is good... And, if your state has income tax, yes, they most likely would want it as well...

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks, so there should be no late fees for missing the first deadline as long as I do what you suggested? And "tax liability" is your "total tax" or the amount you actually pay (or not) after any refunds? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: tax liability is your "total tax" line

Comment: (@JonCuster) Note 'quarterly' is April 15, June 15, Sept. 15, Jan. 15 -- not _equal_ quarters. OP: if you do end up needing estimated payments (tax less withholding and credits > 1k) and didn't pay Q1 timely you _will_ owe a penalty for the underpaid portion and time. Example: if your taxable income will be $50k and tax $5560, and your wife's withholding covers half of it, your required Q1 payment was $625. If you pay that today (which you can) it is 45 days late, so the penalty will be about five dollars. Which they _may_ waive -- just sending a collection letter costs them almost that much.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - indeed. Also one could just increase the wife's withholding to cover the entire anticipated tax bill, and make no quarterly payments. Easier to budget for as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous question I provided the link to the [IRS estimated payments calculator](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/am-i-required-to-make-estimated-tax-payments). You can use it to make the calculations that you need. Generally, you should have at least a rough idea of what your income is, but there are special cases for folks with unpredictable income patters (and yes, you can pay different amounts in different quarters, depending on your income patterns).

To pay the estimated taxes you'll use the form 1040ES. You then report the paid amounts on your annual 1040. There's no documentation necessary, however if you end up not paying enough estimated taxes or withholding you may be subject to the [underpayment penalty](https://www.irs.gov/payments/underpayment-of-estimated-tax-by-individuals-penalty).

W2 is legally required because of the FICA/income tax withholding requirements. Since there are no withholding requirements for the fellowship, you're not getting any "tax" document. You are still getting payslips/have deposit records or have some other documentation about your fellowship, so you can use this as your reference.

Comment: Or there's a 'safe harbor' -- if predicting what your income and tax will be for this year is too hard, you can make estimated payments equalling 100% of your liability for _last_ year (110% if AGI above $150k) and even if you end up next April owing more in tax there will be no 'underpayment' (form 2210) penalty -- _only_ the tax.